# Mass diffusion from a point source in spherical coordinates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mass, differential-equations, diffusion

Is an analytical solution for the mass diffusion from a point source in spherical coordinates even possible? I posted what I thought was a valid solution [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4263839) but the plot doesn't align with my expectation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have the PDE:

$$\frac{\partial C}{\partial t} = D \nabla^2C = D\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r} \left[ r^2 \frac{\partial C}{\partial r} \right]$$

We're looking for a function $C(r,t)$,
with Boundary Conditions:

$$C(r,0)=C_b$$
$$C(0,t)=C_0$$

**Note already that we are missing one value boundary condition because the PDE is second order in $r$.**

Developing the first PDE we get (in 'PDE shorthand'):
$$\frac1D C_t=\frac2rC_r+C_{rr}$$

This type of **second order, linear PDE** is solved by means of **Separation of Variables**. Assume ('Ansatz') that:
$$C(r,t)=R(r)T(t)$$
Insert to get:
$$\frac1D RT'=\frac2r TR'+TR''$$
Divide by $RT$ to get:
$$\frac1D\frac{T'}{T}=\frac2r \frac{R'}{R}+\frac{R''}{R}=-m^2$$
$$\frac1D\frac{T'}{T}=-m^2\tag{1}$$
$$\frac2r \frac{R'}{R}+\frac{R''}{R}=-m^2\tag{2}$$
where $-m^2$ is a **separation constant** and it is a Real number.
$(1)$ is of course very easily solved to:
$$T=c_3\exp(-m^2 D t)$$
where $c_3$ is an integration constant.

---

Slightly reworked from $(2)$, we get:
$$rR''+2R'+m^2 rR=0$$

It can be rewritten as:

$$(rR(r))''+m^2(rR(r))=0$$

Let $S(r)=rR(r)$, then we have:

$$S''+m^2S=0$$

Which has the simple solution:

$$S(r)=c_1\sin mr+c_2\cos mr$$

Back-substitute to get $R(r)$:

$$R(r)=c_1\frac{\sin mr}{r}+c_2\frac{\cos mr}{r}$$

Now apply the boundary condition $C(0,t)=C_0$ as:

$$R(0)=C_0$$

$$\Rightarrow C_0=c_1\frac{\sin m0}{0}+c_2\frac{\cos m0}{0}$$

Because:

$$\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{\cos mr}{r}=\pm\infty$$

it follows that $c_2=0$.

However, you're still stuck with the problem of lacking one BC in $r$. Perhaps $r \to \infty$ then $R(r) \to 0$ could be one?

Another possible BC could be:

$$R(r_o)=0$$

If $r_o$ is very large then it resembles the suggestion above. Inserting into $R(r)=c_1\frac{\sin mr}{r}$ we get:

$$0=c_1\frac{\sin mr_o}{r_o}$$

which boils down to:

$$\sin mr_o=0$$

or:

$$m_ir_o=\frac{i\pi}{2}$$

For $i=0,1,2,3,...$

Thus:
$$m_i=\frac{i\pi}{2r_o}$$

The **eigenvalues** are the $m_i$.

Your final solution will look like:

$$C(r,t)=\Sigma_0^{\infty}\left(B_i\exp(-m_i^2 D t)R_i(r)\right)$$

Where the $B_i$ are determined from the initial condition:

$${B_i} = \frac{2}{r_o}\int_{{\,0}}^{{\,r_o}}{{ {C_b} \sin \left( {\frac{{i\,\pi r}}{r_o}} \right)\,\mathrm{d}x}}\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\hspace{0.25in}i = 0,1,2,3, \ldots$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful response. That boundary condition of $R(\infty)=0$ is acceptable. How does this progress the solution you proposed? I am sort of confused how one could solve for $c_1$ or $c_2$ when the terms they are coefficients for are divergent at $r=0$

Comment: Firstly you need to get rid of the exponentials, using Euler. You also need to transform $C(r,t)$ to, say, $K(r,t)=C(r,t)-C_0$. This way $K(0,t)=0$ (homogeneous!). This tranf. does not affect the derivation because all the derivatives are the same because $C_0$ is a constant. Then apply the chosen BCs, to find $c_1$ and $c_2$. One of them is likely to be $0$.

Comment: Ohhhh it looks like $c_2$ should be $0$ based on third boundary condition you suggested - I think you can tell that without the alteration you mentioned or conversion of exponentials to trig, right?

Comment: My solution contains $i$ in the exponential of my solution i.e. $R(r)=\frac{e^{-i\left(\frac{n \pi}{2}r\right)}}{r}$. Can this be right?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1250117/heat-equation-in-spherical-coordinates, especially the top part of his answer.

Comment: I made a substantial edit.

Comment: I accepted your answer. Thank your your help. If you wouldn't mind though, for completeness, can you demonstrate how to solve for $C_b$?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for accepting. I don't understand your last question though. $C_b$ is a given. It supplies the initial condition: $C(x,0)=C_b$ which for $R(r) \neq 0$ is $T(0)=C_b$.

Comment: I see yes, I forgot my own notation haha - so from the solution, it is evident that $c_3=C_b$ yes?

Comment: No, $C_b=c_3\times c_1$ But you really do not need to concern yourself with that. The solution is complete and correct.

Comment: But what if you were simulating a mass leak such that $C_0 = C_0(t)$?

Comment: I have *literally* no idea. But it's a massive headache, for sure!

Comment: I think I need to add a source term in the original PDE. Also thanks for that link to the other post - I think the insulating BC applies better in my case. I just don't understand where $C_0$ is coming from in their equation or how one proves orthogonality of $R(r)$ and $r^2$

Comment: Yes to a source term. But it renders the whole PDE non-homogeneous. I know what to do with that. But is hard to explain here. An insulating BC would be $R'(r_o)=0$. Not too hard.

Comment: It's still separable though right? Going to make a post tonight I hope - will refer you to it once its up

Comment: If it's still a linear PDE, then separable. You'll probably have to solve the steady state PDE first. Yeah, drop a link. Post the PDE on math.se.

Comment: Sorry its late: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4268624/fourier-transform-constant-determination I didn't go super in depth since I'm fairly confident in my solution. I'm just struggling to determine the constant $C_i$

Comment: thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

You seems to have gone wrong in the section - Casting the Diffusion Equation in Terms of $y(r,t)$, from this step onwards:

$$\Rightarrow \frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial y^2}+\underbrace{\left(\frac{4\sqrt{Dt}}{r}+r\sqrt{\frac{t}{D}}\right)}_{\text{A}} \frac{\partial C}{\partial y}=0$$

$$\Rightarrow \frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial y^2}+A \frac{\partial C}{\partial y}=0$$

From here on you seems to have treated $A$ to be constant, when clearly it is not. $A\equiv A(r,t)=A(y)$ since $y\equiv y(r,t)$.

More specifically, if $$y\equiv\frac{r}{2\sqrt{Dt}}$$ then $$A=\frac{4\sqrt{Dt}}{r}+r\sqrt{\frac{t}{D}}=\frac{2}{y}+ \cdots =A(y)$$

---

To solve it, I don't think that particular substitution of $y$ will work, the reason being although you have a spherically symmetric system, it should be remembered that you are still in 3 dimensions and not 1 dimension. More specifically, here $r=x\hat{i}+y\hat{j}+z\hat{k}$. So you should be looking for some substitution that has to do with [Spherical harmonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics).

Comment: Well it's not constant in $r$ or $t$ but __is__ constant in $y$. I will agree that I do not completely understand how this substitution is valid (and resulted in the correct solution for 1D Cartesian). Did you refer to the guidance document?

Comment: No $A$ is not constant in $y$, I have added some two lines, let me now if that's clear.

Comment: I don't think the problem can be solved the way the OP is trying. Separation of variables is the method of choice for this type of PDE.